# compare spring mvc 3 and struts 2

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, struts2

Just about to start a java EE project.(Biz requirement is under change still.) 
For the web tier, we looked at various java web frameworks and eliminated component-based ones such as JSF, Wicket. Now it comes to spring mvc 3 or struts 2. 
Googled it and found little useful info. Can anyone talk about their pros and cons? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this other [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353359/struts-or-spring-mvc-or-struts-spring) you have a lot of answers comparing struts and Spring. Though many of them don't mention explicitly the version 3 of Spring the comparison would be similar to the version 2.5.

As many of them say, I'd prefer Spring. It makes things easier when you use annotations. One fact I don't like in Struts 2 in comparison with Spring-mvc is that you have to add getters and setters for every property you want to get in the actions. I think Spring is cleaner in this way.

Comment: in S2 2.1+ higher version, you need not to add getter and setters :)

Answer (score 4):

I took over a Struts 2 + Guice web app that used the REST plugin to do convention over configuration. It was very easy to work on at first but I ran into a couple of hurdles that were either difficult or impossible to overcome.

One of these was that I needed to have internal dot/period characters in the path of the URI and Struts 2 + REST did not allow this, as it would interpret the dot to indicate a file extension and try to marshall to the appropriate view (e.g. like catching .xml and .json).

So I ended up rewriting the webapp in Spring 3 and was able to fix all those issues I couldn't handle in Struts 2. I've been much happier with Spring 3 and found it just as fast to code in as Struts 2. I've stuck with annotation based configuration as much as possible and tried to use the JSR versions where ever possible (330 @Inject and 303 @Valid, etc), so that if I decide to get rid of Spring I am not stuck with custom Spring annotations.

My vote is Spring 3.

Comment: Its quite late to comment however if someone reads this post later they might want to know. 1) Struts2 has convention plugin which allows to use convention over configuration. 2)If you are lost in convention in a large project there is struts-config-browser plugin which shows the actual configuration (xml+annotation). 3) There are 3 ways of debugging struts application: browser,xml,console for evaluating OGNL expressions and ValueStack

Comment: the problem you faced is not because of struts but because of the REST plugin, which does this misinterpretation. You could have solved the problem by taking out REST plugin from you application rather than converting the whole thing into spring3.

Comment: I did actually go down this path - but the app (written by someone else) was heavily dependent on that plugin, requiring me to write a lot of extra code as a result. IMHO the plugin should've been able to handle it (Grails has no problems with dots in URLs, as a comparison). Furthermore, this plugin is one of the Struts 2 selling points and is clearly a core plugin, and thus reflects back on Struts. I did say it was just one of a number of issues I had with Struts at the time and clearly stated this was my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

@Javi
You have various options in Struts2 to avoid these getter and setter one of them id ModelDriven interceptor

Well my vote is for Struts2 since i am working on it from so long but this does not mean Spring MVC is bad i have worked on it also and its equally good..

Choice is all yours and it depends what word you like most Spring or Struts